# Golang httpClient CA certificates default location?

Tags: windows, ssl, go, ca

I have a `go` program that connects to an internal API using the `httpClient` (it's all generated by `swagger-codegen`).

The internal API is using `https` and internal certificates with our internal CA.

On my Windows laptop, it works fine without specifying any CA.

On a Linux server, it fails with a `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error.

I believe our Windows corporate laptops have CA installed by default, and that `golang` is able to get those CA without any config.

**Hence i would like to know where is `go` checking for CAs on both Linux and Windows**, so i could compare the setup between both OSes and install the correct CA on Linux.

Comment: Linux certs locations are defined here https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go

Comment: Thanks, i found this in another answer, and the ones for Windows here: https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_windows.go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Golang picking up root CAs from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051213/where-is-golang-picking-up-root-cas-from)

Comment: yes, as stated in the answer, but it's only for Linux whereas i was also asking for Windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Windows: [`https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_windows.go)

For Linux: [`https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go)

Found via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051432/2041863).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the Linux half of your question: Most Linux distributions come with `strace`, a utility for tracing system calls.

To start monitoring the server's file-related syscalls:

```
$ sudo strace -fp $MY_SERVER_PID -e trace=file
```

The server may only try to access the certificates the first time it attempts to initiate a secure connection, so it may be necessary to restart the server and start tracing it before the first connection. Another option is to start the server via strace:

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=file /usr/bin/my-server
```

If your tracing is successful, you will find something along the lines of

```
[pid 19691228] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```