# Kratos- Social sign-in - How to use an oidc provider having a self signed signature?

Tags: ory, kratos

I'm trying to connect my hosted Kratos with an OIDC provider that has a non trusted certificate.

Is there an elegant way to fill to Ory Kratos a list trusted CA certificate ?

I'm facing this error when connecting to my app with my custom oidc provider:

```
"reason": "Unable to initialize OpenID Connect Provider: Get "https://my-custom-oidc-provider/.well-known/openid-configuration": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Where is Golang picking up root CAs from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051213/where-is-golang-picking-up-root-cas-from) to see where CAs are loaded from. There you can add it to the appropriate CA source for your setup.