# Where is Golang picking up root CAs from in MacOS?

Tags: macos, go, cert

I found it explaining Linux: [Where is Golang picking up root CAs from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051213/where-is-golang-picking-up-root-cas-from)

I want to understand how it's done on MacOS. Thanks.

Comment: The answer you linked to says that the certificate roots for Linux are defined in `root_linux.go`. It's not hard to guess what the filename for macOS/Darwin would be. Have you looked there?

Comment: In root_linux.go the paths and directories are available (e.g. /etc/ssl/certs). But none found in root_darwin.go. The root cause is, I'm behind company's proxy (Zscaler) and need to send the correct cacert.pem. I want to understand how Golang is including the cert first before asking for help. Thanks @JörgWMittag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS (and also Windows), [Go does not load root certificates from the filesystem](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/crypto/x509/root_darwin.go;l=128). Instead, Certificate.Verify calls [c.systemVerify](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/crypto/x509/root_darwin.go;l=13) which uses APIs provided by the OS to validate certificates.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for pointing out, appreciate!! My take is, macOS going to return sets of certs from its 'internal secret location' (certs := macOS.CFArrayCreateMutable()). Anyway to override and pass custom certs?

Comment: Yes. Set [tls.Config.RootCAs](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config.RootCAs).